# How to omit empty lists using aeson deriveJSON?

Tags: haskell, aeson

Using the aeson deriveJSON it is easily to omit Nothing values, e.g.:

```
data Person = 
  Person {
    ssn :: Maybe Text,
    phone :: [Text]
  }

$(deriveJSON defaultOptions{omitNothingFields=True} ''Person)
```

I would like to also omit empty lists in order to keep the JSON compact.
Is there a general to omit empty lists using deriveJSON, without hand rolling instances?

Comment: You could perhaps change the type to `Maybe (NonEmptyList a)` and write an appropriate To/FromJSON setup for that. I think it more clearly encodes the kind of information you're trying to convey, perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you cannot currently do that.

I guess it follows the philosophy that the structure of the object should roughly align with the type; from that view point, having `{... phone: [] ...}` or even `{... phone: null ...}` for non-existant fields is "more typed" than leaving them out of the object.

If the reason you want to keep the JSON "compact" is not for elegance, but e.g. bandwidth reasons, `gzip` or things like [JSONH](https://github.com/WebReflection/JSONH) might achieve almost the same savings transparently, without you having to change the structure of your objects.